# Java string concat in stringbuilder call

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

As far as I know, StringBuilder helps to reduce memory usage by not creating temporary string instances in the string pool during concats.
But, what happens if I do sth like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("bu");
sb.append("b"+"u");
```

Does it compile into

```
sb.append("b");
sb.append("u");
```

? Or it depends on optimalization flags? Or I loose the whole benefit if stringbuilders?
Or this quetion makes no sense? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It compiles to `sb.append("bu")`, because the compiler translates the concatenation of multiple String litterals to a single String litteral.

If you had

```
String a = "a";
sb.append(a + "b");
```

it would compile it to

```
String a = "a";
String temp = a + "b"; // useless creation of a string here
sb.append(temp);
```

So you should prefer

```
sb.append(a);
sb.append("b");
```

in this case.

Comment: Is this something relatively new to Java?  I've always been led to belive string concatenation would result in multiple strings as they are immutable?  Or does this only apply when concatenating String variables?

Comment: No, it's not new. It's very useful to be able to properly format (on several lines) a long string literal, like a long SQL or JPQL query, for example.

Comment: for the 2nd code sample not only a String will be created, also an additional StringBuilder will be created.

Comment: @JBNizet: Given `String cd = "cd";`, how does the following String get optimized? `String abcdef = "a" + "b" + cd + "e" + "f";`?? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Since `"b" + "u"` is an expression which is evaluated at compile time, it will be compiled just as if you had `"bu"`.

```
 0: new #2; //class StringBuilder
 3: dup
 4: ldc #3; //String bu
 6: invokespecial   #4; //Method StringBuilder."<init>":(String;)V
 9: astore_1
10: aload_1
11: ldc #3; //String bu
13: invokevirtual   #5; // StringBuilder.append:(String;)LStringBuilder;
```

If you on the other hand had two string variables, this optimization wouldn't kick in:

The following snippet...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("bu");
String b = "b", u = "u";

sb.append(b + u);
```

...gets compiled as:

```
0:  new #2; //class StringBuilder
3:  dup
4:  ldc #3; //String bu
6:  invokespecial   #4; //Method StringBuilder."<init>":(String;)V
9:  astore_1
10: ldc #5; //String b
12: astore_2
13: ldc #6; //String u
15: astore_3
16: aload_1
17: new #2; //class StringBuilder
20: dup
21: invokespecial   #7; //Method StringBuilder."<init>":()V
24: aload_2
25: invokevirtual   #8; //Method StringBuilder.append:(String;)StringBuilder;
28: aload_3
29: invokevirtual   #8; //Method StringBuilder.append:(String;)StringBuilder;
32: invokevirtual   #9; //Method StringBuilder.toString:()String;
35: invokevirtual   #8; //Method StringBuilder.append:(String;)StringBuilder;
```

I.e. something similar to

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("bu");
String b = "b", u = "u";

StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
temp.append(b);
temp.append(b);
String result = temp.toString();

sb.append(result);
```

As you can see in line 17-21 an extra `StringBuilder` is created for the purpose of concatenating `a` and `b`. The resulting `String` of this temporary `StringBuilder` is then fetched on line 32 and appended to the original `StringBuilder` on line 35.

---

(The bytecode was generated by the `javap` command which is part of the JDK. Try it out, it's really simple!)

Comment: You guessed what I really wanted to ask :) So optimalization happens when I have literals only, in case of variables, always use append.

Comment: @aioobe: Given `String cd = "cd";`, are the following two equivalent as well? `String abcdef = "a" + "b" + cd + "e" + "f"; <==>`String abcdef = "ab" + cd + "ef";`? Thanks!

Comment: @Gevorg, I believe so, why don't you try it out with `javap`? :-)

Comment: Hahah, it's not. Just do `javac Test.java` and then `javap -c Test`.

Comment: @aioobe: I did it, it was glorious! :) It compiles to `"ab" + cd + "e" + "f";` I tried with different inputs as well, basically only the literals before the variable get optimized. Very interesting.. I guess it might be related to the natural order of '+'..

Comment: @Gevorg - no.  It happens because the JLS specifies that it happens.

Comment: @StephenC: I always try to understand "why" things happen in a certain way, "why" they are implemented one way instead of another, and even "why" the JLS has been written the way it is. A better outcome for the optimization above would have been `"ab" + cd + "ef"`, and if that doesn't happen there must be a reason... I believe that it can derive from the fact that the '+' operator is left-associative (1+2+"3"=>(1+2)+"3"=>33 while "1"+2+3=>("1"+2)+3=>123). I couldn't find a detailed description of string compiler optimization in the JLS, could you point me exactly at where to look at?

Answer (score 0):

No, the `"b" + "u"` will create an immutable `b` string, an immutable `u` string, and then create a third immutable `bu` string that gets passed into the `StringBuilder` instance.

Comment: No it won't.  See @aioobe's answer.

Comment: I can't believe the compiler is not smart enough to not create the single letter literals, or, without that much negation, I believe the compiler is smart enough to only create the `bu` string.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger - it is not "smartness".  It is simply a matter of implementing the Java Language Specification.

Comment: @Stephen - to be read as: the people who developed and implemented the compiler are smart enough...

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger - reading and implementing the spec is your definition of smart?  To be fair though, there is a good chance that the spec mirrored the first compiler not the other way around.

Comment: @Stephen - I think I need to attend some English courses - is it so hard to understand it was a sarcastic comment (to the answer)? (not sure if the spec states that the string `b` and `u` should not be created, neither that they should)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger - 1) I'm not being sarcastic.  2) The JLS really *does* specify that constant string concatenations are evaluated at compile time.  The compiler writer does not have a choice in this.  Hence my assertion that this is not a sign of smartness on the part of the compiler or the compiler writer.

Comment: @Stephen - OK, I see its my English. 1) I meant that **my** 1st comment was (a try to be) sarcastic. As I have not included `@Stephen` in that comment, it should be clear that it was about the answer and not about your comment, which I haven't seen when I wrote the comment. 2) agreed, but that is not the point I am addressing. I meant that the compiler writer would not be smart to create the two additional strings - `b` and `u` - as affirmed in the answer. 3) my 1st comment has the same meaning as yours 1st comment, but this discussion is leading nowhere (prob. wrong place too) - Im out.

Answer (score -1):

WRONG:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("b"+"u");
```

CORRECT:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("b").append("u");
```

BEST: //Since you knew what's going to be in there already! ;)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("bu");
```

`:)`

**EDIT**

I guess my answer above is not correct when dealing with literals only...

`:/`

Comment: Actually, the "WRONG" version is equivalent to the "BEST" one.  See @aioobe's answer.

Comment: @StephenC: Do you know how/if/why the following gets optimized by the compiler: `String abcde = "a" + "b" + c + "d" + "e";?

Comment: @Gevorg - I know it does because the JLS says it does, and if a compiler didn't do this then it wouldn't be a valid Java compiler.